# Which portion should I be looking at to modify the Path-Algorithm? ( I want to make 3 versions with different pathing algos)

Tags: python, path, artificial-intelligence

class path_finder ():

```
def __init__ (self):
    # map is a 1-DIMENSIONAL array.
    # use the Unfold( (row, col) ) function to convert a 2D coordinate pair
    # into a 1D index to use with this array.
    self.map = {}
    self.size = (-1, -1) # rows by columns

    self.pathChainRev = ""
    self.pathChain = ""

    # starting and ending nodes
    self.start = (-1, -1)
    self.end = (-1, -1)

    # current node (used by algorithm)
    self.current = (-1, -1)

    # open and closed lists of nodes to consider (used by algorithm)
    self.openList = []
    self.closedList = []

    # used in algorithm (adjacent neighbors path finder is allowed to consider)
    #self.neighborSet = [ (0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0) ]
    #changed to Up Left Down Right
    self.neighborSet = [ (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0) ] 

def ResizeMap (self, (numRows, numCols)):
    self.map = {}
    self.size = (numRows, numCols)

    # initialize path_finder map to a 2D array of empty nodes
    for row in range(0, self.size[0], 1):
        for col in range(0, self.size[1], 1):
            self.Set( (row, col), node() )
            self.SetType( (row, col), 0 )

def CleanUpTemp (self):

    # this resets variables needed for a search (but preserves the same map / maze)

    self.pathChainRev = ""
    self.pathChain = ""
    self.current = (-1, -1)
    self.openList = []
    self.closedList = []

def FindPath (self, startPos, endPos ):

    self.CleanUpTemp()

    # (row, col) tuples
    self.start = startPos
    self.end = endPos

    # add start node to open list
    self.AddToOpenList( self.start )
    self.SetG ( self.start, 0 )
    self.SetH ( self.start, 0 )
    self.SetF ( self.start, 0 )

    doContinue = True

    while (doContinue == True):
        # GNode + HNode = FNode (Anjos)
        thisLowestFNode = self.GetLowestFNode()
        # If not @end node, and not not lowest cost (Anjos)
        # then set lowest f node to current         (Anjos)
        # Add to ClosedList (current)               (Anjos)
        if not thisLowestFNode == self.end and not thisLowestFNode == False:
            self.current = thisLowestFNode
            self.RemoveFromOpenList( self.current )
            self.AddToClosedList( self.current )
        # an offset within an array or other data structure object is an integer indicating the distance (displacement) (Anjos)
        # from the beginning of the object up until a given element or point, presumably within the same object         (Anjos)
            for offset in self.neighborSet:
                thisNeighbor = (self.current[0] + offset[0], self.current[1] + offset[1])
        # if 1st and 2nd are smaller than 0, if it's 1st and 2nd size isn't smaller than itself -1, and if it's not a wall (Anjos)        
                if not thisNeighbor[0] < 0 and not thisNeighbor[1] < 0 and not thisNeighbor[0] > self.size[0] - 1 and not thisNeighbor[1] > self.size[1] - 1 and not self.GetType( thisNeighbor ) == 1:
                    cost = self.GetG( self.current ) + 10
        # then the cost is whatever our current cost was ^+10.^ (Anjos)            
                    if self.IsInOpenList( thisNeighbor ) and cost < self.GetG( thisNeighbor ):
                        self.RemoveFromOpenList( thisNeighbor )
        # if neighbor is in OpenList, and cost is smaller than G of thisNeighbor, remove from OpenList (Path Choice nullified) (Anjos)                
                    #if self.IsInClosedList( thisNeighbor ) and cost < self.GetG( thisNeighbor ):
                    #   self.RemoveFromClosedList( thisNeighbor )

        # if NOT thisNeighbor inOpenList and NOT thisNeighbor inClosedList - add thisNeighbor to OpenList   (Anjos)
        # set G (previous cost)of thisNeighbor to cost                                                      (Anjos)
        # calculate thisNeighbor's H(Manhattan) and F (Total)                                               (Anjos)
        # set thisNeighbor's parent node to current                                                         (Anjos)
                    if not self.IsInOpenList( thisNeighbor ) and not self.IsInClosedList( thisNeighbor ):
                        self.AddToOpenList( thisNeighbor )
                        self.SetG( thisNeighbor, cost )
                        self.CalcH( thisNeighbor )
                        self.CalcF( thisNeighbor )
                        self.SetParent( thisNeighbor, self.current )
        # else stop                                                                                         (Anjos)
        else:
            doContinue = False
        # If this isn't the lowest path cost then return False                                              (Anjos)                
    if thisLowestFNode == False:
        return False
        # Restart Path Logic?                                                                               (Anjos)             
    # reconstruct path
    self.current = self.end
    while not self.current == self.start: # While the current is NOT the start (Anjos)
        # build a string representation of the path using R, L, D, U
        if self.current[1] > self.GetParent(self.current)[1]:       # current[1] > parent(current[1])       (Anjos)
            self.pathChainRev += 'R'                                # add Right                             (Anjos)
        elif self.current[1] < self.GetParent(self.current)[1]:     # current[1] < parent(current[1])       (Anjos)
            self.pathChainRev += 'L'                                # add Left                              (Anjos)
        elif self.current[0] > self.GetParent(self.current)[0]:     # current[0] > parent(current[0])       (Anjos)
            self.pathChainRev += 'D'                                # add Down                              (Anjos)
        elif self.current[0] < self.GetParent(self.current)[0]:     # current[0] < parent(current[0])       (Anjos)
            self.pathChainRev += 'U'                                # add Up                                (Anjos)
        self.current = self.GetParent(self.current)             # get parent from current node              (Anjos)
        self.SetType( self.current, 4)                          # set current's Type to 4 ?? No clue what 4 is besides the intermitent ghost    (Anjos)

    # because pathChainRev was constructed in reverse order, it needs to be reversed!
    for i in range(len(self.pathChainRev) - 1, -1, -1):
        self.pathChain += self.pathChainRev[i]

    # set start and ending positions for future reference
    self.SetType( self.start, 2)
    self.SetType( self.end, 3)

    return self.pathChain

def Unfold (self, (row, col)):
    # this function converts a 2D array coordinate pair (row, col)
    # to a 1D-array index, for the object's 1D map array.
    return (row * self.size[1]) + col

def Set (self, (row, col), newNode):
    # sets the value of a particular map cell (usually refers to a node object)
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ] = newNode

def GetType (self, (row, col)):
    return self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].type

def SetType (self, (row, col), newValue):
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].type = newValue

def GetF (self, (row, col)):
    return self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].f

def GetG (self, (row, col)):
    return self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].g

def GetH (self, (row, col)):
    return self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].h

def SetG (self, (row, col), newValue ):
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].g = newValue

def SetH (self, (row, col), newValue ):
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].h = newValue

def SetF (self, (row, col), newValue ):
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].f = newValue

def CalcH (self, (row, col)):
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].h = abs(row - self.end[0]) + abs(col - self.end[0])

def CalcF (self, (row, col)):
    unfoldIndex = self.Unfold((row, col))
    self.map[unfoldIndex].f = self.map[unfoldIndex].g + self.map[unfoldIndex].h

def AddToOpenList (self, (row, col) ):
    self.openList.append( (row, col) )

def RemoveFromOpenList (self, (row, col) ):
    self.openList.remove( (row, col) )

def IsInOpenList (self, (row, col) ):
    if self.openList.count( (row, col) ) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def GetLowestFNode (self):
    lowestValue = 1000 # start arbitrarily high
    lowestPair = (-1, -1)

    for iOrderedPair in self.openList:
        if self.GetF( iOrderedPair ) < lowestValue:
            lowestValue = self.GetF( iOrderedPair )
            lowestPair = iOrderedPair

    if not lowestPair == (-1, -1):
        return lowestPair
    else:
        return False

def AddToClosedList (self, (row, col) ):
    self.closedList.append( (row, col) )

def IsInClosedList (self, (row, col) ):
    if self.closedList.count( (row, col) ) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def SetParent (self, (row, col), (parentRow, parentCol) ):
    self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].parent = (parentRow, parentCol)

def GetParent (self, (row, col) ):
    return self.map[ self.Unfold((row, col)) ].parent

def draw (self):
    for row in range(0, self.size[0], 1):
        for col in range(0, self.size[1], 1):

            thisTile = self.GetType((row, col))
            screen.blit (tileIDImage[ thisTile ], (col * 32, row * 32))
```

Comment: Too much code, not really a question. (You should ask something more precise than just "What should I change in that huge code to make 3 algorithms ?"

Answer (score 2):

`FindPath` looks like the place to start.  However, I don't think this code will help you if you want to implement totally different algorithms.  What exactly are you trying to do?
Edit:

I think you should look into changing `GetLowestNode` and `CalcF` and `CalcH` too.  I think that's where the next node to look at, current cost to reach the tile is, and the heuristic are calculated.

Comment: Well I was planning to implement a couple different basic ones, Djikstra's, Depth First Search, Breadth first Search, hill-climbing, etc.